# How can I reliably get Framer Studio to see Sketch Beta 3.0.4 (8156)?

Tags: framerjs

I have:

1. Downloaded and opened Sketch Beta 3.0.4 (8156)
2. Created a new document in Sketch and saved it
3. Opened a new document in Framer Studio 1.0.168 (264)

Yet, when I click `Generate`, I get `Sketch not Running: Please open Sketch`.

How can I reliably get Sketch integration to work with Framer Studio?

Comment: Beta is beta, use the non-beta Sketch and you'll be fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a bug I just fixed: https://www.facebook.com/groups/framerjs/permalink/537879059672503/